# How can I download NetSuite saved search data using Python?

Tags: python, netsuite

I would like to download data from NetSuite Saved searches using Python. Someone gave the following solution in an older post:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

session = OAuth1Session(
    client_key='**YOUR_KEYS**',
    client_secret='**YOUR_KEYS**',
    resource_owner_key='**YOUR_KEYS**',
    resource_owner_secret='**YOUR_KEYS**',
    signature_type='auth_header',
    signature_method='HMAC-SHA256',
    realm='**YOUR_NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER**',
)

r = session.get(

 url='https://**YOUR_NETSUITE_ACCOUNT**.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=**YOUR_SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID**&deploy=1&searchId'
                '=**YOUR_SAVED_SEARCH_ID**',
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                     }
        )

netsuite = r.json()
print(netsuite)
```

But, where can I find the client key, secret, and the resource owner key, secret? I couldn't comment in that old post to ask where to get them due to not having enough reputation points.

I found the consumer key, secret, and token id, secret but if I use them as client and resource owner keys (just to test), I get the following error:

```
{'error': {'code': 'SSS_INVALID_SCRIPTLET_ID', 'message': 'That Suitelet is invalid, disabled, or no longer exists.'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello for this you would need to create an integration within Netsuite , this will generate the consumer key and secret .

Then next step is to create access tokens for this integration , this will generate the access key and secret .

Finally you would need to call a restlet URL in which some developer or you write the code to return what you want .

the realm is basically the account id

For the error you posted , you should log into netsuite go to setup->roles ->view login audit trail , use the advanced search and add in the results the detail and the app name . find your app and check in the detail what the exact issue is. Hopefully you have your restLet in released status as well.